# "A fatal alert message was received from our peer" SSL error on Cargo build

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am tying to build a Rust project on Debian that uses the `rand` library but am getting an SSL error on `cargo build`:

```
→ cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to load source for a dependency on `rand`

Caused by:
  Unable to update registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  SSL error: 0xffff8880 - SSL - A fatal alert message was received from our peer; class=Ssl (16)
```

Trying to curl the URL works fine:

```
→ curl https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
<html output>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the environment variable `CARGO_HTTP_CHECK_REVOKE=false` fixed this issue for me e.g.

```
export CARGO_HTTP_CHECK_REVOKE=false
cargo build
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the cause of this issue is network filtering by ISPs (in the UK: WebSafe, HomeSafe, Parental Controls or similar).

Either some of the domains rust uses are being blocked, or large response payloads aren't properly handled by ISP filtering software.

The solution is to either **disable these filters in your ISP's control panel**, or **switch your DNS** (as the filters are all DNS based).

If I switch to `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf` on linux this issue goes away completely.

I discovered this after encountering a [similar issue with brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/666#discussioncomment-480587).